# modify module but not by hacking

Tags: node.js

I'm using node.js modules installed via npm.

I'm wondering what is the best way to modify a node module functionality.
Let's say I have a module called Handler and there is a method called foo which takes a request object and returns a response object.

1) What if I want to do something to the response before it gets returned.

Do I just modify the code itself ?

Are there any articles on this ?

UPDATE --

Also, the original function is modifying a few objects that is not being returned, But I want to modify them too. How would I handle that ?

Answer (score 1):

What i would do here is to create a wrapper around the function, and then change it in there. If that was unclear, here's some code:

```
var myModule = require('myModule');
var myModuleFunc = myModule.myFunc;
myModule.myFunc = function() {
    var res = myModuleFunc.apply(this, arguments); // call the function, and pass along context and arguments
    res = transform(res); // whatever you do the response
    return res;
};
```

Comment: Thanks - Also, the original function is modifying a few objects that is not being returned, But I want to modify them too. How would I handle that ?

Comment: They should be modified just the same when you call the original function.